# Laravel: issue with relation

Tags: laravel

I have had some issue with my project on Laravel 5.2.  I have two tables: **Journal** and **JournalDetails** with OneToOne relation. Model **JournalDetails** has constructor with parameters. So, I had next code in **Journal** model:

```
public function journalDetail()
{
    return $this->hasOne('JournalDetail', 'journal_id');
}
```

I want to get JournalDetail:

```
@if (isset($j->journalDetail))
    <td>$j->journalDetail->name</td>
@else
    <td></td>
@endif
```

But I get an error during this one:
**Missing argument 1 for App\Models\JournalDetail::__construct(), called in C:**\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php on line 740 and defined (View: C:**\resources\views\pages\admin\get_journal.blade.php)**

For testing I deleted parameters in JournalDetail and there are no errors. It is a laravel bug? Why constructor is called?

Comment: journalDetail relation returns a Collection Object which contains JournalDetail object laravel calls its constructor to make JournalDetails object. As a patch supply their default value like `func($param=null){ }`

Comment: Please show your JournalDetail constructor.

Answer (score 0):

try `$j->journalDetail[0]->name`