# issue with laravel elquent relation

Tags: laravel, relationship, laravel-queue

I have a column name creator in the table storing the user id. When fetching records, I am using belongs to relation. I receive data, but I am not able to display it.

Note: [This thread doesn't solve my issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43256781/laravel-issue-with-relation)

Category table scheme

```php
Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name')->unique();
            $table->string('slug')->unique();
            $table->string('banner')->nullable();
            $table->boolean('status')->default(false);
            $table->bigInteger('creator');
            $table->bigInteger('moderator');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

user table scheme

```php
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Category Model:

```php
   public function creator(){
        return $this->hasOne(User::class, 'id',  'creator')->select('id', 'name');
    }
```

Category Controller code:

```php
$records = Category::with(['creator'])->paginate(env('REC_LIMIT'));
```

data I get it:

```php
"data":[{"id":1,"name":"Uncategorized","slug":"uncategorized","banner":null,"status":1,"creator":{"id":1,"name":"demon slayer"},"moderator":1,"created_at":"2019-11-03 12:08:33","updated_at":"2019-11-04 11:11:01"},
```

note if with clause is removed in the query, I get:

```php
"data":[{"id":1,"name":"Uncategorized","slug":"uncategorized","banner":null,"status":1,"creator":1,"moderator":1,"created_at":"2019-11-03 12:08:33","updated_at":"2019-11-04 11:11:01"},
```

in blade file, I what am doing is below code to print creator user name instead of their record id.

```php
$record->creator->name 
//or
$record->creator[0]->name
```

currently i get this:

```php
Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
Trying to get property 'name' of non-object (View: /Users/dragonar/Dev/pdp/resources/views/backend/category/index.blade.php)
```

Comment: Please consider rewriting your question. It's hard to read. I tried my best to improve it regarding the language, but I didn't understand your issue entirely.

Comment: Could you add your user and category table? If you do we will be able to understand you better.

Comment: issue is pretty simple. i want the user name who had created the category or moderated the category record. for this i have creator and moderator column in category table. now i am using with clause to get creator name and id (so that i can link his profile as a hyper link to name). when if i just return the record as json. i can see data under creator. but then i do $record->creator->name. it gives the mentioned error.

Comment: don't have a relationship method named the same as a field/attribute ... Eloquent will resolve the attribute via the dynamic property before it resolves a relationship by that name, `$record->creator` will always be the 'field' from the table, not the relationship in this case ... need better naming of your foreign keys

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried instead of

```
public function creator(){
    return $this->hasOne(User::class, 'id',  'creator')->select('id', 'name');
}
```

This:

```
public function creator(){
    return $this->hasOne(User::class, 'user_id')->select('id', 'name');
}
```

Or change the name of the function from `creator()` to `user()`.

And then in your blade `$record->user->name`.

This what I found on the laravel docs:

> Eloquent determines the foreign key of the relationship based on the model name. In this case, the Phone model is automatically assumed to have a user_id foreign key. If you wish to override this convention, you may pass a second argument to the hasOne method: return $this->hasOne('App\Phone', 'foreign_key');
>   [Source](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one)

Comment: You are right that changing creator to user works but i also have a column for moderator. This kinda  create new issue.

Comment: Assuming that my first suggestion of using 'user_id' instead of 'id' didn't work. What error did you get? Exactly the same error or different than before?

Comment: What if you try my first suggestion but instead of having a 3rd argument 'creator'. Don't have a 3rd argument at all. I changed my post so you can copy and paste the function I first suggested.

Comment: no i don't get data as user table have id and not user_id as a column. so the third parameter is required.

Comment: It seems that if you keep the `with` clause you already get the creator. Have you tried `$record['creator']->name` or at least something like it? (If you use what you first had ofcourse) Incase it still doesn't work you could also try `$record[0]->creator->name` or `$record[0]['creator']->name` anything like this.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up renaming creator to creator_id and in model, function is creator. like this now i can access desired data $record->creator->name or $record->creator->id.

what i wanted was instead of creator returing me id from original code, i could have been able to do $record->creator->name or $record->creator->id, directly.